# Access to Azure File Storage via VNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I faced with follow problem and hope that I can find the way for solving with your help.
I created follow Azure resources:

1. WebApp Service (Asp.Net Core web application)
2. FileStorage
3. VirtualNetwork

All resources created in one resources group. I trying to upload file from my WebApp to File storage via VNet (I need to secure storage so it must be inaccessible from outside internet).

Virtual Network have subnet, which have setup a Microsoft.Storage - Service endpoints. This sub net is included In Storage firewall settings.

For work with Azure storage I use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage package.
When I trying to get access to storage from webapp I get 403 error.
For access I use 'primary file service endpoint' - `https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/`

What have I missed?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure File shares can’t be accessed from Azure App Service web apps. Refer this [feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s) where the feature was declined.